# htaccess: How to redirect to 404 if url parameter is missing or invalid?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Assume the following folder structure on the webserver (Apache):
`https://somedomain.com/parentfolder/childfolder`.

Using `.htaccess`, I'd like to display the `childfolder` and any of it's children (files as well as folders) only the URL contains a certain parameter. For example, the page should be shown if it's requested by:

```
https://somedomain.com/parentfolder/childfolder?secretparameter=secretvalue123
```

However if

- the value of parameter `secretparameter` is not exactly `secretvalue123` or
- the parameter `secretparameter` is missing,

then a 404 error should be returned.

Do you have any ideas how the .htaccess rules would look like to accomplish this? Your help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

So, if the query string is not `secretparameter=secretvalue123` when requesting a resource within the `childfolder` then issue a 404 not found. You can do something like the following at the top of the `.htaccess` file in the document root using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !=secretparameter=secretvalue123
RewriteRule ^parentfolder/childfolder - [R=404]
```

This blocks the request if the query string is not exactly equal to `secretparameter=secretvalue123`. (You don't need the `L` flag here when specifying a non-3xx code as it is implied.)

You could simplify the `RewriteRule` slightly if instead, you placed these directives in the subdirectory you want to protect. ie. at `/parentfolder/childfolder/.htaccess`. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404]
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I don't know why, but it's just not working: _https://somedomain.com/parentfolder/childfolder can still be accessed through the browser, regardless if secretparameter=secretvalue123 is part of the URL or not. Looks like something's wrong here... Well, there's an index.php file at that location. Could this be the cause of the failing redirect?

Comment: Try (temporarily) removing the RewriteCond directive (comment out with a #) - is it blocked now? An index.php file itself is not the problem, however, do you have any other .htaccess files that also contain mod_rewrite directives?